# My client doesn't send correctly to server

Tags: c, queue, pthreads, posix

I have problems with my code.

I have this client with posix queue. Is a posix queue comunication with a conc server.
The question is down.

```
mqd_t server;
mqd_t client;
struct request req; //char *name, int pos, int op...
struct reply rep; //int num, int ret...
struct mq_attr attr;

attr.mq_maxmsg = 1;
attr.mq_msgsize = sizeof(struct reply);
client = mq_open("/CLIENT", O_CREAT|O_RDONLY, 0700, &attr);
server = mq_open("/SERVER", O_WRONLY);


req.name = name;
req.op = 3;

mq_send (server, (const char *) &req, sizeof(struct req),0);
mq_receive(client, (char*)&rep, sizeof(struct reply), 0);

mq_close(server);
mq_close(client);
mq_unlink("/CLIENT");
```

And this server

```
struct db mydb[100]; //Struct with char*name....
  for (int i = 0; i<100;i++){
  strcpy(mydb[i].name,"");
  mydb[i].vec =NULL;
  mydb[i].size =0;
}

mqd_t server;

struct request mess;
struct mq_attr q_attr;
pthread_attr_t t_attr;

q_attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
q_attr.mq_msgsize=sizeof(struct request);
server = mq_open ("/SERVER", O_CREAT|O_RDONLY, 0700, &q_attr);
  if (server == -1){
  perror("Er");
}

pthread_mutex_init (&mutex_msj, NULL);
pthread_cond_init (&cond_msj, NULL);
pthread_attr_init(&t_attr);

pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&t_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

while(1){
  pthread_t thid;

mq_receive(server, (char*) &mess, sizeof(struct request), 0);
```

AND HERE IS THE PROBLEM. WHEN I PRINF MESS.OP I WOULD RECIVE "3". The number that I asigned the client. And when I do this, mess.op have 0, not 3.

```
pthread_create(&thid, &t_attr, (void*)func, &mess);
...
...
...
...

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is too messy, could you please format it so it's readable?

Comment: Please read the tour, and don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you are calling `pthread_create()` with a local ([*or automatic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)) variable `mess` which is sometimes deallocated before the thread is actually started. You need to allocate `mess` on the heap and be very careful to free it at the appropriate time.

Also `(void *) func` doesn't look right because,

- The correct type is [`void *(*)(void *)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)

and it would appear as if you were ignoring compilation warnings, or forcing them to disappear by randomly casting a pointer to the type the compiler suggested.

Comment: Yes, but the fault appears in the previous command line. When I receive mess with mq_receive. Mess.op would be 3 not 0, and all datas received in mess is 0. I dont know why.